# How to use apply method with string array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, apply

Can someone explain to me why I am not able to use the apply method on string array correctly?

```
function speak(line) {
     console.log(line);
}
var whiteRabbit = {type: "white", speak: speak};
speak.apply(whiteRabbit, ["Burp!","Skree","Hello"]);
```

The output is `Burp`, why not the whole array? And How to achieve that with the apply method?

Comment: what is fatRabbit ?

Comment: sorry it should be whiteRabbit....how can i correct that

Answer (score 1):

[Function#apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) spreads the array into functions parameters, since your only parameter is `line`, the first item in the array is assigned to it, and the rest are ignored.

**btw** - since the `speak` function doesn't use `this` in any way, the 1st parameter of `apply` doesn't matter in this case.

If you'll add more params to the function you can see how it works:

```js
function speak(a, b, c) {
     console.log(a, b, c);
}

speak.apply(null, ["Burp!","Skree","Hello"]);
```

If you need to display an array of unknown length, it's better to invoke the function using [Function#call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), and then iterate the array, or convert it to something presentable. For example:

```js
function speak(arr) {
  console.log(arr.join(' '));
}

speak.call(null, ["Burp!", "Skree", "Hello", "Cats"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

> The **`apply()`** method calls a function with a given `this` value, and `arguments` provided as an array (or an [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Working_with_array-like_objects)).

You take only the first element of the array as parameter `line`. If you take more parameters, you could see the rest of the array as well.

```js
function speak(line, line1, line2) {
    console.log(line);
    console.log(line1);
    console.log(line2);
}

var whiteRabbit = {
    type: "white",
    speak: speak
};

speak.apply(whiteRabbit, ["Burp!", "Skree", "Hello"]);
```

If you like to use the values as array, you yould use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and iterate the values.

```js
function speak() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function (s) {
        console.log(s);
    });
}

var whiteRabbit = {
    type: "white",
    speak: speak
};

speak.apply(whiteRabbit, ["Burp!", "Skree", "Hello"]);
```

Wit ES6 you could use [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```js
function speak(...args) {
    args.forEach(s => console.log(s));
}

var whiteRabbit = {
    type: "white",
    speak: speak
};

speak.apply(whiteRabbit, ["Burp!", "Skree", "Hello"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So make it dynamic, I should use arguments.length. Right?

Comment: @rajeev or even better rest/spread syntax: `function speak(...args){ console.log(...args);}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `fatRabbit` is meant to be `whiteRabbit` and that your question is why you only see `Burp!` instead of the full array.

The reason is that `apply` uses the array to call your function with *discrete arguments*, so the first entry shows up as the `line` parameter, and you're not seeing the others because you don't have parameters for them.

If you want to see the array, use `call` rather than `apply`; then `line` will refer to the array, not just the first entry:

```js
function speak(line) {
     console.log(line);
}
var whiteRabbit = {type: "white", speak: speak};
speak.call(whiteRabbit, ["Burp!","Skree","Hello"]);
```

Alternately, add more parameters in the method (`speak(line1, line2, line3)`).

---

In a comment, you've asked:

> Can you show how to make it dynamic?

If by "dynamic" you mean it logs as many entries as it gets, I'd use `call` (as above) and a loop:

```js
function speak(lines) {
    lines.forEach(function(line) {
        console.log(line);
    });
}
var whiteRabbit = {type: "white", speak: speak};
speak.call(whiteRabbit, ["Burp!","Skree","Hello"]);
```

That's using `forEach`, but [you have lots of other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you show how to make it dynamic?

Comment: @RajeevHanda: What do you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: @RajeevHanda: I've taken a guess at what you mean by dynamic above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more parameters

```js
function speak(line, line2, line3) {
     console.log(line, line2, line3);
}
var whiteRabbit = {type: "white", speak: speak};
speak.apply(whiteRabbit, ["Burp!","Skree","Hello"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may let the rabbit say one word after another:

```
 ["Burp!","Skree","Hello"].forEach( speak );
```

If you want to change the context too:

```
["Burp!","Skree","Hello"].forEach( word => speak.call(rabbit, word));
```